# ASP.NET Button Click Event Issue (postback)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, postback

The issue that i'm having is that trhough a button1 upon click shall save the data entered in the textboxes (see code) however when the page is postback the data is not saved (no confirmation message appears) then if i click again it does saves the record, sometimes takes more than 3 times until the data is stored per confirmation message.

**Is this a Con.Dispose Issue??? Shall i use con.close?**
Note: in the code i have Con.CLOSE however the page is deployed under Con.Dispose()

Note2: i'm planning to fix more "novice" issues found in the code but urgent question remains in the postback issue.

```
    ' *--------Empty Text Validation-------*
    If TextBox10_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" AndAlso TextBox3_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" AndAlso TextBox4_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" AndAlso TextBox5_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" AndAlso TextBox6_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" AndAlso TextBox7_AddData_LabInvest.Text <> "" Then

        ' *--------SQL Insert command-------*
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [LabInvest] (ID_LabInvest, LabInvest_Load, LabInvest_SeqRef_CH, LabInvest_SeqRef_Year, LabInvest_Owner, LabInvest_Subject, LabInvest_DueDate, LabInvest_Code, LabInvest_QSNCCode, LabInvest_OpenByOwner, LabInvest_OpenDateOwner, Status_Text, Status_Int ) VALUES(@ID_LabInvest, @LabInvest_Load, @LabInvest_SeqRef_CH, @LabInvest_SeqRef_Year, @LabInvest_Owner, @LabInvest_Subject, @LabInvest_DueDate, @LabInvest_Code, @LabInvest_QSNCCode, @LabInvest_OpenByOwner, @LabInvest_OpenDateOwner, @Status_Text, @Status_Int)"
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("ID_LabInvest", TextBox10_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_Load", "N/A")
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_SeqRef_CH", TextBox1_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_SeqRef_Year", TextBox2_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_Owner", TextBox3_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_Subject", TextBox4_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_DueDate", TextBox5_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_Code", TextBox6_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_QSNCCode", TextBox7_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_OpenByOwner", TextBox8_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("LabInvest_OpenDateOwner", TextBox9_AddData_LabInvest.Text)
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("Status_Text", "Stage 1 - Just Added")
        SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.InsertParameters.Add("Status_Int", "1")


        Try
            SqlDataSource_AddData_LabInvest.Insert()

            ' *--------Get Unique ID-------*
            Dim Con As New SqlConnection
            Dim SQL As String
            Dim com As SqlCommand = Con.CreateCommand
            Con.ConnectionString = "removed"
            Con.Open()
            SQL = "SELECT ID_LabInvest FROM LabInvest WHERE ID_LabInvest=" + TextBox10_AddData_LabInvest.Text
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Con)
            Dim obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Label1_AddData_LabInvest.Text = "Your record ID is: " + obj.ToString()


            ' *--------Get Stage-------*
            Dim SQL2 As String
            SQL2 = "SELECT Status_Text from LabInvest WHERE ID_LabInvest=" & obj
            Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand(SQL2, Con)
            Dim obj2 = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
            Label2_AddData_LabInvest.Text = "Record Stage: " + obj2.ToString()
            con.close()
            Button4_AddData_LabInvest.Enabled = False

            ' *--------SQL Audit Insert command-------*
            Dim Usercheck As String
            Usercheck = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [AuditTrial] (ID_Table, AuditTableName, AuditAction, AuditUser, AuditValue1Before, AuditValue2Before, AuditValue1After, AuditValue2After, AuditMasterReason, AuditMasterChange) VALUES(@ID_Table, @AuditTableName, @AuditAction,  @AuditUser, @AuditValue1Before, @AuditValue2Before, @AuditValue1After, @AuditValue2After, @AuditMasterReason, @AuditMasterChange)"
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("ID_Table", obj)
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditTableName", "LaboratoryInvestigations_Add")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditAction", "Added New Record")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditUser", Usercheck)
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditValue1Before", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditValue2Before", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditValue1After", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditValue2After", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditMasterReason", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.InsertParameters.Add("AuditMasterChange", "N/A")
            SqlDataSource_LabInvest_Audit.Insert()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1_AddData_LabInvest.Text = "Duplicate NumberID, Please Review Data"
        End Try

    Else
        Label1_AddData_LabInvest.Text = "Please Fill All Options"
    End If
```

Comment: Did you add breakpoints and debug code? Are you allowing it finish processing before hitting submit button again and again?

Comment: Is the code you posted part of the relevant click event handler? Are there any other event handlers in the page?

Comment: @DavidW no that's the entire code for that click event.

Comment: @rs. Im not click a lot of times the button, click once (nothing happened) wait 5 seconds and clicked again (now it does saves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was found as the application was residing in a Web Servers Farm with NLB, therefore the blank post-back was due to the NBL redirecting the user to another server from the original connection. (different solutions may apply link NO Cache, Connection Affinity,etc) hope it helps someone in the future.